# Eigenvectors of $AA^T$ as linear linear combinations of columns of $A$

Tags: linear-algebra

I read that any eigenvector of $AA^T$ (or $A^TA$)  is a  linear combination of columns of $A$.

I made some attempts to derive this result, but to no avail. If possible, could you provide a mathematical derivation of this result?

Comment: This doesn't seem right to me : $AA^T$ is symmetrical, thus there is a base of eigenvectors of it. Thus it can only be true if $A$ is surjective, in which case it is trivial.

Answer (score 2):

For general rectangular matrices, it'll only be true that the eigenvectors corresponding to *nonzero* eigenvalues of $AA^T$ are linear combination of columns of $A$.  It won't be true for $A^TA$, just by dimension considerations.  This can all be related to the [SVD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular_value_decomposition), by the way.

Suppose $A$ is $n\times m$, so that it maps $\Bbb{R}^m$ to $\Bbb{R}^n$.  Recall the following facts:

- The columns of $A$ span the range of $A$, which is a subspace of $\Bbb{R}^n$.
- Eigenvectors corresponding to nonzero eigenvalues of $AA^T$ will be in the range of $A$, since if $AA^Tv = \lambda v$, $v$ must be in the range of $A$ since $v = A(\frac{1}{\lambda}A^Tv)$ i.e. we've expressed $v$ as $Aw$ for some $w\in \Bbb{R}^m$.

Combine the above two facts and you have that eigenvectors of $AA^T$ can be expressed as a linear combo of columns of $A$.